# Trigger javascript object event in powershell

Tags: javascript, powershell

I have the following code for webscraping a page using powershell. I would like to trigger a javascript event called 'change' which exists on the Select DOM element on the webpage. In this case, the 'change' event updates the values in table based on the value of the Select DOM element.

```
$url = "https://www.investing.com/currencies/gbp-nzd-historical-data" 
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$ie.visible = $true; 
$ie.navigate($url); 
while ($ie.Busy() -and $ie.ReadyState -ne 4){ sleep -Milliseconds 6000 }

$ie.Document.getElementById("data_interval").selectedIndex = '1' // Select DOM element

$ie.Document.getElementById("data_interval").fireEvent("change")
```

Errors:

```
    Invalid argument.
At C:\Users\user\Documents\test.ps1:11 char:1
+ $ie.Document.getElementById("data_interval").fireEvent("change")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

Comment: If you try to log out the `$ie.Document.getElementById("data_interval")`, is it correct on the console? Maybe it does not find the wished element.

Comment: @tenkmilan Yes it does find the DOM element

Answer (score 0):

Use "**onchange**" instead "**change**". "**change**" function is from jQuery library that you will be getting under inspect element -> Event list, but through Powershell you are fetching javascript DOM object function list, So there ideally you should use **onchange**.

Comment: They are two seperate events though. There is no 'onchange' event defined on the dom element only 'change'.

Comment: Yes I did try. Perhaps you could run the code to try and recreate my issue?

Comment: I tried and it's working. Dropdown list values are getting changed with respect to the selected index.

Comment: The dropdown does update however the table does not update based on the new value selected in the dropdown (selectedIndex)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Success]

Using "**onchange**" it's working as expected. You can test the same by changing "**selectedIndex**" values

Comment: Yes dropdown does update with the selected index '1' (Weekly) but the values in the table do not update which is what the 'change' event does not 'onchange'. I can trigger this change event directly from the google chrome console but I need to recreate this part in the powershell script
var selectr = document.getElementById('data_interval').selectedIndex = '1'; 
selectr.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))